# fatal error when trying to calculate string distance

Tags: r

I try to add a column with string distance of two columns of a tibble (70k rows) using `adist` (from `util`), but I keep getting "R encountered a fatal error".

This is the line giving me the error:

```
my_tibble <- my_tibble %>%
  mutate(dist = adist(column1, column2))
```

How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Does rowwise execution (call `rowwise()` before `mutate()`) help?

Comment: Thanks @I_O, with rowwise() is works!

Comment: The error occurred because R ran out of RAM to run the calculations.